# Why isn't my error handler handling exceptions thrown from async middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, error-handling, async-await

If I have a middleware I can normally throw an error like this:

```js
function throwMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  throw new Error(`Something went wrong in your async middleware.`);
}
```

This will get caught in my centralized error handling middleware.

However when I have an asynchronous middleware I get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`:

```js
async function throwMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 200);
  });
  throw new Error(`Something went wrong in your async middleware.`);
}
```

Full code:

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
async function throwMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 200);
  });
  throw new Error(`Something went wrong in your async middleware.`);
}

app.get("/", throwMiddleware, (req, res, next) => { // route for GET /
  console.log("get /");
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => { // centralized error handler
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err);
  }

  console.log("error caught in middleware:", err.message);
  return res.send("oops");
});

app.listen(3500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instread of `throw`ing the error I put it in the `next` call. But I don't know why throwing works in a synchronous middleware and not in an asynchronous middleware.

```js
async function throwMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 200);
  });
  next(new Error(`Something went wrong in your async middleware.`));
}
```

Comment: Throwing is like return, just with an error. Both of them stop the execution of the code.

Comment: yes, but why does the error handler catch an error thrown from a synchronous middleware but not an asynchronous middleware? I would think they'd work the same in both.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own error handler in express, [see the documentation here.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err)
  res.status(500).send('this is handled error')
})
```

Make use your declare this `app.use` last.

Comment: That is already in the code in the original post. The problem is it doesn't handle the error when thrown from with the async middleware.

Comment: I don't think my question was clear so I edited the original question to clarify the problem